# Passing more than 2 vectors in R

Tags: r

I want to compute `e^(ax+b) over a=-1:1` and `b=-1:1` for various values of `X`. I want the output in the form a list of 5 elements. Each element in the list is 3X3 Matrix.

I did achieve this using Outer and Vectorize.

```
 sigm = function(a=0,b=0,x){
 return(exp(x*a+b))
 }

 sigm1 = Vectorize(function(a=-1:1,b=-1:1,x){

 outer(a,b,sigm,x)
 },SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Now, `sigm1(x=1:3)` gives the required output

```
 [[1]]
      [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
 [1,] 0.1353353 0.3678794 1.000000
 [2,] 0.3678794 1.0000000 2.718282
 [3,] 1.0000000 2.7182818 7.389056

[[2]]
       [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.04978707 0.1353353  0.3678794
[2,] 0.36787944 1.0000000  2.7182818
[3,] 2.71828183 7.3890561 20.0855369

[[3]]
       [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.01831564  0.04978707  0.1353353
[2,] 0.36787944  1.00000000  2.7182818
[3,] 7.38905610 20.08553692 54.5981500
```

The only draw back with this code snippet is I am using the default values of `a=-1:1` and `b=-1:1`. When I try to pass the same during function calling, it goes haywire. E.g.

```
sigm1(-1:1,-1:1,1:3)

[[1]]
      [,1]
[1,] 0.1353353

[[2]]
 [,1]
[1,]    1

[[3]]
     [,1]
[1,] 54.59815
```

I am unable to figure out why passing the arguments is making this difference in output.

Comment: From the documentation: "The arguments named in the `vectorize.args` argument to `Vectorize` are the arguments passed in the `...` list to `mapply`. Only those that are actually passed will be vectorized; default values will not."  So, when you pass the parameters, it's vectorizing across all three parameters ([a = -1, b = -1, x = 1], then [a = 0, b = 0, x = 2], then [a = 1, b = 1, x = 3]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sapply` to create your *vectorized* function

```
sigm = function(a, b, x){
    return(lapply(x, function(xx) sapply(b, function(bb)
        sapply(a, function(aa) exp(xx*aa+bb)))))
}
sigm(a = -1:1, b = -1:1, x = 1:3)
#[[1]]
#          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
#[1,] 0.1353353 0.3678794 1.000000
#[2,] 0.3678794 1.0000000 2.718282
#[3,] 1.0000000 2.7182818 7.389056

#[[2]]
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] 0.04978707 0.1353353  0.3678794
#[2,] 0.36787944 1.0000000  2.7182818
#[3,] 2.71828183 7.3890561 20.0855369

#[[3]]
#           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] 0.01831564  0.04978707  0.1353353
#[2,] 0.36787944  1.00000000  2.7182818
#[3,] 7.38905610 20.08553692 54.5981500
```